# Resolving Powershell Module Location

Tags: powershell

I want to get the file or folder path of the psm1 module in which a class is defined.
Until the latest windows update I had stable solution for this for many years using the AssemblyQualifiedName of the TypeInfo of the class.

```
$type = [MyType]
$path = $type.AssemblyQualifiedName.Split(",")[1].Trim()
```

Previously the AssemblyQualifiedName looked like this:
{ClassName}, {PathToFile}, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

With the newest update the Assembly Qualifiedname changed to this:
{ClassName}, PowerShell Class Assembly, Version=1.0.0.36, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

It doesn't seem to be related to the Powershell Version since i can reproduce the new unwanted behavior on 5.1.19041.3031 and 5.1.22621.1778 but also have a VM (windows update not installed) with version 5.1.20348.1366 where it still works.

Does anyone an idea how to get the original behavior back or an alternative solution to dynamically resolve the file location?

The only somewhat possible workaround would be to create a Method in each class which provides the ModuleLocation:

```
  static hidden [string]GetModuleLocation() {
    return $PSScriptRoot
  }
```

But thats a pretty messy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
[int].Assembly.Location
```

There's also `CodeBase` property.

EDIT:
Solution above used to work even for types defined in a module. But I just tested, and on my machine it still works in powershell 5.1, but not anymore in 7.3.

I found a different solution, but it requires that you first import all modules that may define the types (`-ListAvailable` won't help).  It lists all types defined by the modules, then you can filter. Works both on ps 5.1 and 7.3

```
(Get-Module | ? ImplementingAssembly) | % {
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Module = $_.Name
    Types = $_.ImplementingAssembly.DefinedTypes
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Module     Types                                             
------     -----                                             
TestModule {MyType, MyType_<staticHelpers>, MyEnum}
TestModulx {xType, xType_<staticHelpers>}
```

Ofcourse it's not much help if same type can be implemented in many different modules, and you need to find where did already loaded type came from during runtime.

Comment: Both Properties are Empty for classes defined in a psm1 File.
For .Net classes this would be the correct way.

Comment: I am using PS 5.1 myself, and it worked fine until last weeks windows update. 
Quickly tested your edit and I think i can solve it like this. Thank you